# Are there other uses for the value of RMS current besides heating computations?

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, math, rms

For most purposes I've personally encountered, RMS current and voltage have been useful only for computing heat losses in a resistor. Do RMS current or voltage have other applications besides computing heat loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMS is nearly always associated with power, but there are many times you want to know power that don't involve heating resistors. For example:

- The power sent to a speaker becomes sound waves. The RMS value of the waveform corresponds to the perceived loudness of the sound.
- Signal-to-noise ratios are power ratios. Therefore, you want to compute the RMS values of the signal waveform and the noise to get a SNR value.
- In electrical power transmission, it's the RMS values of voltage and current that correspond to the power delivered to, say, a motor (assuming the power factor is near unity, of course).

There are many more examples. The point is, in most forms of AC signal analysis, the RMS value is nearly always the more useful value — although there are times when you need to be aware of the peak value as well.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not specifically imply current or voltage.

If you have two signals (A and B) produced by separate generators and you want to know the result when these signals are added together you use RMS addition: -

Combined signal (RMS) = \$\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\$

If you tried adding the peak (or peak to peak) values you get a result that is meaningless.

Comment: Careful with that formula.  Its often true but I can think of lots of examples where it isn't like two sine waves of the same frequency.  In phase rms = A+B, 180 deg out of phase and they its A-B or B-A depending on how you are measuring.

Comment: @WarrenHill I said from "separate generators" in my answer and this would normally imply that the two signals are NOT phase locked - it's only phase locked signals where the formula breaks down - maybe I should be clearer on that?

Comment: Exactly, I'm sure you know when it breaks down.  My comment was for the benefit of others who may apply it blindly.

Comment: @WarrenHill OK good idea.